# Rewriting cakephp path in cakephp 3.0

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cakephp, url-rewriting, cakephp-3.0

I have a need to remove the app folder from the URL. 
Example URL is: `mydomain.com/cake_app/vechicles/add`
What I need to have instead is `mydomain.com/vechicles/add`

NOTE! In the root of mydomain.com I have a WordPress installation running, so I only need to route users to cake application if there is a  `vechicles` controller name in the URL.

I have found many examples for how to do it via .htaccess files, but these were for CakePHP <3.0 and seem not to work with the current version.

Comment: just move the contents of cake_app one folder up. The "many examples" you've already found all still apply. Also note that this question probably means you're using a development style install - [you shouldn't be doing that](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#production).

Comment: The reason why I do not want to move it one folder up is that I have a wordpress install in the root.
Thanks for the install link.

Comment: That's a rather significant detail to omit - please edit the question and indicate which urls should be rewritten and which not. In the absence of information right now you've got a logical conflict.

Comment: Thank you for guiding, just updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add .htaccess to your domain root folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    cake_app/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) cake_app/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

**UPDATE**

> NOTE! In the root of mydomain.com I have a WordPress installation running, so I only need to route users to cake application if there is a  `vechicles` controller name in the URL.

Add this rule in .htaccess before any of wordpress rules.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^vechicles$    cake_app/    [L]
    RewriteRule    ^vechicles/(.*) cake_app/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now  mydomain.com/vechicles/ show your cake_app. Inside cake app make routing

**CakePHP 2**

`Router::connect('/add', array('controller' => 'vechicles', 'action' => 'add') );`

**CakePHP 3**

```
$routes->connect('/add', ['controller' => 'vechicles', 'action' => 'add']);
```

Comment: This works, but if I go to the root of domain where I have a WordPress installed, it brings me straight to cake app, where what I need is WordPress.

Comment: You change your question.

Comment: Yes, I have just updated it. Sorry for not providing it straight from the beginning.

Comment: Works as a charm now. Thank you.