# Redirect URL with .htaccess to Subdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, redirect

I am running a website and a CakePHP server on the same service. The CakePHP is in a subdirectory. I would like the URL http://www.example.com to direct to my index.html in the root and http://www.example.com/app to redirect to CakePHP webroot.

These are my current .htaccess files

In var/www/html:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule  ^$    app/webroot/  [L]
    RewriteRule  (.*)  app/webroot/$1  [L]
</IfModule>
```

In var/www/html/app:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ /webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) /webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

In var/www/html/app/webroot:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Edit**

The question is how would I set up my htaccess so that I can get to my CakePHP webroot with the URL http://www.example.com/app but on the index var/www/html if I use the URL http://www.example.com. With my current htaccess it redirects both URL to the CakePHP webroot.

Thank you

Comment: I'm a little confused, what is your question?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.

The question is how would I set up my htaccess so that I can get to my CakePHP webroot with the URL http://www.example.com/app but on the index var/www/html if I use the URL http://www.example.com. With my current htaccess it redirects both URL to the CakePHP webroot.

Comment: In which directory is your CakePHP root?

Comment: the CakePHP is in the app folder on  /var/www/html. There is also an index.html in there.

Comment: The way you've described this is _very_ confusing - it is unclear (and yes, I've read the question) whether you've put your application in the domain root (`/var/www/html`) or in a subfolder (so that e.g. `/var/www/html/app/app/webroot` exists). It is not normal for "app" to be in the url. It's also not clear what version of CakePHP you are using, since it doesn't match 3.x I can guess you're using 2.x - but I shouldn't need to guess. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have root access to apache config?

Im guessing your cake app is not the only thing you want to run on this domain so you are wanting to set it up as an alias on `/app`?

I recommend setting up `/app` as an Alias in apache config first.

Im more familiar with doing this on Ubuntu 14.04 (my example is specific to ubuntu) but the concept will be the similar on other Linux distributions

Enable the alias mod:

```
sudo a2enmod alias
```

using nano or other favourite text editor you need to add a file to apache config:

```
sudo touch /etc/apache2/sites-available/mycakeapp.alias.conf
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/mycakeapp.alias.conf
```

For the file content:

```
Alias /app "/var/www/html/app/webroot"
<Directory "var/www/html/app/webroot">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Enable the config file so apache knows to load it:

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
sudo a2ensite mycakeapp.alias.conf
```

Restart apache to load in the new config:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

then rewrite the base in your `.htaccess` file in `/app/webroot`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /app
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Done. `http://www.example.com/app` will now point to and act as your applications base directory

the other .htacess files `/.htaccess` and `/app/.htaccess` can be removed as they will never be hit. Not compulsory to point the virtual host straight to the webroot but it is better practise as it will stop users being able to access or view other folders in the app directory

**Centos / RedHat setting up apache alias**

Adding this to the bottom of your `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file and restarting apache should do the trick. `service httpd restart`

```
Alias /app "/var/www/html/app/webroot" #make sure this is actually your applications root
<Directory "var/www/html/app/webroot">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**The Short Answer to your question**

If you dont have root access to apache config or just want to skip the alias adding step you can just add the `RewriteBase /app` line to your webroots .htaccess

Delete or edit the `.htaccess` in `/var/www/html` so that the `myexample.com/` doesnt redirect to the cake app

Comment: I tried the short answer but got a 404 response:

The requested URL /webroot/ was not found on this server.

I'm using a Amazon EC2 Linux distribution. I have root access, but I can't locate the the apache2 folder.

Comment: I really think that in your case setting up your application as an alias is the way to go. After a quick google it looks like your flavour of Linux is similar to redhat/centos... Please checkout my **Centos / RedHat setting up apache alias**  section I just added and see if it is any help

Comment: Thank you for your answers, It seems there was something wrong with my CakePHP setup. I got it working by reinstalling CakePHP and removing the .htaccess in /var/www/html.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33018144/1127933

Your folders structure:

```
/var/www/html/
  .htaccess <----- edit
  index.html
  app/ <------ cakephp
    bin/
    config/
    src/
    ...
```

**Inside var/www/html add .htaccess file**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^app$    app/    [L]
    RewriteRule    ^app/(.*) app/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I tried the steps given in the link and change the var/www/html file, but I still got a 404 error:

The requested URL /webroot/ was not found on this server.

Comment: It seems more likely they are _not_ using 3.x - in which case [the file you're suggesting to edit is part of the standard install](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/2.8.3) - It's not good advice (if that is the case) to suggest editing the root .htaccess file

Comment: Thank you for your answers, It seems there was something wrong with my CakePHP setup. I got it working by reinstalling CakePHP and removing the .htaccess in /var/www/html.